# Show Image on Loading - WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm using this code for showing an image from assets folder on Loading, but the problem is, the image shows up only on the first loading that is when the application starts, this is because the image is displayed ate the background of my app and hence, it is not visible. i want to show it up on the webview screen.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //hide loading image
        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //show webview
        findViewById(R.id.webView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    />
```

Comment: please post your xml - layout

Answer (score 1):

try to implement this..

```
findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
    mWebView.loadUrl("URL");

public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: the method onpagefinished is undefined for the type activity.